# Connecting 2 virtual devices android in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to connect 2 virtual devices in my localhost in eclipse so i could test my server-client chat but was unsuccessful and with different versions android API too.
So o though the problem could be that i didn't had any configuration.
When tried use commands to connect the 2 devices it appears:

C:>telnet localhost 5554
telnet localhost 5554

C:>'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

To integrate cmd.exe in eclipse i used this tutorial:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-open-a-windows-command-prompt-in-my-console.html?page=1

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, but any help I appreciate

Comment: `telnet` is not going to connect two devices.  Depending on what your program has implemented, you might be able to telnet to one device to interact with it and pretend that you are the other device.  You could even have two telnet sessions going in separate terminals (one to each device), but the two sessions would be independent, not linked.  Also, telnet will only connect to server sockets - for your two devices to directly talk, one must be a server and the other a client.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 7 then telnet.exe is not installed by default. [You have to add it manually.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.how-to-enable-telnet-client-in-windows-7.aspx)